# Which among exact, phrase and broad justify my given keyword ? I am using google keyword tool

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console, keywords

I am using google keyword tool, now I want to know, when I type back office in mumbai, without any quotes, which of these would represent that.

[back office jobs in mumbai]    - exact

"back office jobs in mumbai"    - phrase

back office jobs in mumbai  - broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`back office jobs in mumbai - broad` This one matches that. Without quotes or other modifiers the default search is broad.